# Session Helper Methods in Michael Hartl Tutorial Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm going through Michael Hartl tutorial on Ruby on Rails and I'm having trouble understanding some logic.  Note that the logic works, it's just not resonating with me on what's actually happening.

In this chapter we're logging in users and creating a session.  Here the helper methods:

```
module SessionsHelper
    # Logs in the given user.
    def log_in(user)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
    def logged_in?
      !current_user.nil?
    end
end
```

Depending on whether the user's logged on or not we change the navigation with this conditional:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
   do something....
<% else %>
   do something else...
<% end %>
```

As I understand it, the code checks to see if the user is logged in by calling the logged_in? method.  The logged_in? method calls the current_user method to see if it's nil.  If it is nil it returns false, if it's not nil it returns true.  As a test I tried to change the logged_in? method to the following:

```
def logged_in?
  !@current_user.nil?
end
```

When I run this method for some reason, after I log in with credentials that are authenticated, @current_user returns nil.  Why is this?  Note this works if I change it back to the original logged_in? method where I'm just calling the method current_user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was formulating my question I figured this out.  In the later case

```
def logged_in?
  !@current_user.nil?
end
```

@current_user isn't set yet because the current_user method was never called.  To test, I changed the method to the following:

```
def logged_in?
  current_user
  !@current_user.nil?
end
```

where the method was called first and then @current_user was evaluated.  It worked without issue.  The original method works because current_user returns @current_user to the logged_in? method as either a user object or nil (@current_user is set as the last line in the method -- it's the only line, so it's retuned implicitly to the logged_in? method).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question since you have that figured it out while I was trying to answer. But I want to clarify on some points.

In rails, in fact most of the web application, we track a user's log in state in server's [session](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-rails-sessions-work/). the `log_in` method in your code does that.
Then when the new request comes in to a controller that requires authentication, we check the session if there is a stored user. If it exists then the request is authenticated, else it's unauthenticated. So, `logged_in?` method's actual responsibility is to check the session.

However, it is quite common that we want to access the authenticated user's attributes in the controller and/or views. So we set an @current_user variable on the controller so that you can access the User object of authenticated user. Again, using an instance variable directly is not a good practice. So we wrapped it in the `current_user` method.

Then you might ask, why don't we store the whole user object in session? Because it is bad to store much in session(see [here](http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/01/14/session-store-and-security/)). So, we just store the id and use it to get the user from db.

Here is where the ||= part comes in. ||= caches the result of db. Otherwise, we would be hitting db every time we call current_user method.

Hope this clarifies a bit on what's actually happening.